# does empty function has security risks?

Tags: security, function

I have to implement the following interface in my contract

```
interface IMetadataRenderer {
    function tokenURI(uint256) external view returns (string memory);

    function contractURI() external view returns (string memory);

    function initializeWithData(bytes memory initData) external;
}
```

but my contract does not need `initializeWithData` function so I want to implement it as an empty function but I'm not sure that if it introduce any security risks.

```
function initializeWithData(bytes memory initData) public {}
```

Comment: Why don't you remove it from the interface if your contract doesn't need it?
And if it's nota doable then making it private would be a good choice.

Comment: @ZartajAfser good points, but do you think If this function is has security problem ?

Comment: No, it doesn't have any security problem. It will just take up unnecessary space